# Hibernate - function to check if persistent properties have changed

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is there a built-in function which can check if any property of a persistent entity differs from the one of a detached instance?

*Else I will have to write a generic criteria function to check it myself using the class meta data.*

Comment: Why would you need that? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: There are several use-cases. Using push service in presentation layer to check if data has changed (Versioning would be more appropriate). On 1:1 relations enforce creating new instance of child property instead of update in case child table is referenced by other tables.